# Why is my UIView category causing warnings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, categories, objective-c-category

I added a category to UIView to hold some transition helper methods.  The methods are all working; however, I get compiler warnings:

> warning: 'UIButton' may not respond to '-fadeOutWithDuration:'

My "UIView+Trans.h" file looks like this:

```
@interface UIImage (trans)
- (void) fadeOutWithDuration:(CGFloat)duration;
@end
```

My "UIView+Trans.m" file looks like this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "UIView+Trans.h"

@implementation UIView (trans)
- (void) fadeOutWithDuration:(CGFloat) duration {
    //...
}
@end
```

And I'm calling the method like this:  (and have #import "UIView+Trans.h" at the top of each file that uses the category method.)  I've also tried casting the UIButton* to a UIView*.

```
[self.myButton fadeOutWithDuration:kFadeOutDuration];
```

I've used the "NSString+Reverse" example from this [Categories Example](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) article successfully in the same project and without the pesky warnings.

Comment: Looks correctly for me, you may need to remove import and try to copy again, check file name stuff:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your header file, you've declared the category on `UIImage` not `UIView`.

Comment: Wow!  I cannot believe how many times I've gone over those lines and missed that!  Also interesting that it was working...  Thanks so much!

Comment: The reason it works is because you've defined the implementation correctly, and therefore the category exists at runtime and the method gets activated correctly.  In this instance the only reason for your category header is to prevent compiler warnings ;-)